# Azure Active Directory Token

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I'm new to using Azure Active Directory authentication with a Web API. Right now the login page on my Single Page Application simple directs the user to the Microsoft login page where they enter their credentials and then are redirected back to my SPA. Upon the redirect the access token is now part of the URL. Is it possible to get that token via JSON rather than part of the URL? Is that a security risk making the token visible to user like that? If there is no other way to get the token what's the best way of processing that? Should I read the URL and pull the token from there and then redirect the user again to the actual website?

Comment: It's all handled for you by MSAL.js. Just go through the documentation and this will all make sense.

Comment: @evilSnobu What documentation? The link you gave me yesterday? That was for someone else's project. Do I have to merge my project with theirs in order for this to work? That project has a boat load of errors in it.

Comment: @evilSnobu Also, it looks like this project is designed to be hosted on Azure. I don't want this on Azure. I just want to use Active Directory authentication. Nothing fancy. This is the project I'm referring to:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi-v2/tree/ad810c3c56f56f5b980e2a93a51b48c4b4117349

Comment: [This is the library](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js). Follow the Docs and quickstart for SPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be mindful in implicit flow the token will still be maintained at the client site (local storage normally). So even if you are hiding the token from URL , you still will be storing at client side and that's one of things you have to manage in SPA. You will have to send token with every HTTP request to your web api to get that authenticated on that end.

In implicit flow tokens are shortlives and you can't issue refresh token for longer period of access. For this kind of flow you need to use official library (ADAL.js)

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js

**More resources**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow

Answer (score 1):

You can use ADAL.js library to acquire the token. There is a pre defined function which you have to call after the Ad authentication or at the beginning check if you are logged in, you can use isauthenticated function to check if you have already logged in, and use getaccesstoken function to acquire the token after authentication.